# determine furthest Point away from other Point's

Tags: java, grid, point

I am creating a simple game with some simple AI implementations on some of the ingame computer steerd players.

I have a list of `Point` that represent possible moves for the player. I need to write a method that moves the player to the `Point` furthest away from possible enemies in that list. I illustrated it with the picture:

[image]

Numbers represent Points poistion in List

What I want is for player(4) to move to either `Point` in position 2 or 6 that are furthest away from any enemies. I've managed to solve this if there is one enemy by iterating the list and using the `distance()` method of `Point` to determine which point is furthest away. But the code must work even if there are several enemies in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, how about you do it the other way round:

```
1. Iterate over each point.
2. Find out how close it is to its closest enemy.
3. Choose the point that is furthest from its closest enemy.
```

There's a lot of potential for early-outs:

```
Within the loop store the currently furthest point. 
If you are then inspecting another point and find out
it has a closer enemy, you can immediately skip to the
next point
```

[edit]: also if you're working with a grid as above, you can

```
1. Check if there's an enemy on the currently processed 
   point *before* iterating through other enemies. That way
   you can exclude it as early as possible.

2. If it's a densely populated grid, consider doing a breadth-first
   flood-fill starting at the current point. That might find the closest
   enemy much faster than iterating though all of them.
```